# How to de-serialize kafka internal topic __consumer_offsets data

Tags: python, deserialization, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to read data from Kafka internal topic __consumer_offsets using kafka-python client. I create consumer and successfully fetched data but the problem is data is serialised and look like it's in wire format , I want to deserialize this data into some readable format, i figured out that there are key_deserialize and value_deserialize options available in kafka consumer api but the problem is i couldn't figure out what value should to give to these fields , Could anyone please help me in this ?

my consumer code looks like

```
 consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=Settings.instance().kafka_server,
                                     consumer_timeout_ms=2000,
                                     enable_auto_commit="False",
                                     exclude_internal_topics="False",
                                     value_deserializer = bytes.decode, # not working•
                                     group_id=self._group_id
                                    )
```

and the consumed message looks like ::

```
ConsumerRecord(topic='__consumer_offsets', partition=26, offset=12983, timestamp=1520765864606, timestamp_type=0, key=b'
\x00\x01\x00\x16console-consumer-56707\x00\x06events\x00\x00\x00\x00', value=b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01b\x14\xb5\x8a\x9d\x00\x00\x01b\x19\xdb\
xe6\x9d', checksum=-1872169212, serialized_key_size=38, serialized_value_size=28)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to implement custom Serializer(at producer end) and Deserializer (at consumer end). Make sure to put same custom value class on class path at consumer end as that of producer.

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements Deserializer<ValueClass> {
    public CustomDeserializer() {
    }

    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
    }

    public ValueClass deserialize(String s, byte[] MessageBytes) {
        ValueClass eEventMessage = null;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            eEventMessage = (ValueClass)objectMapper.readValue(MessageBytes, ValueClass.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
  //               your stuffs
        }

        return eEventMessage;
    }

    public void close() {
    }
}
```

Set this custom class at consumer end properties.

Comment: This consumer is reading from internal Kafka topic (__consumer_offsets) I don't have any producer for it. My question is which serialization approach is used to serialize kafka internal topic.